# c# how to FormWindowState.Normal

Tags: c#, forms, splash-screen, behavior, minimized

i have this code:

```
    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        about About = new about();
        About.ShowDialog();
    }
```

it minimizes the parent window state to minimized and displays a splash form.

my question is when the splash screen closes how do i get back to parentwindowstate.normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    about About = new about();
    About.ShowDialog();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ShowDialog instead of Show; you can add

```
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

after the ShowDialog call.  (ShowDialog is blocking, unlike Show.)

Answer (score 0):

Call ShowDialog() like this:

```
About.ShowDialog(this);
```

Then, in the About form's FormClosing event, put:

```
this.Parent.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
```

Comment: Or after the ShowDialog() : works. but when i try it in the about form it doesn't compile.

thanks to all for your help.

Comment: Duh to myself. I suppose that's what you get when you try to be the fastest gun in the West.